# Inverse of a analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity, analytic-functions

Let $f$ be a map on the closed unit disc $\bar{\mathbb{D}}$ in $\mathbb{C}$ such that $f$ is analytic on $\mathbb{D}$ and continuous on $ \bar{\mathbb{D}}$. Can you tell under what condition will $f$ be invertible under point-wise multiplication. Will the inverse also be analytic on $\mathbb{D}$ and continuous on $ \bar{\mathbb{D}}$? If yes why?

Comment: The equivalent condition is:  $f$ does not vanish on $\bar{\mathbb{D}}.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Can you tell why?

Comment: If $g(z)f(z)=1$ for $|z|\le 1$ then $f(z)\neq 0$ for all $|z|\le 1.$ The inverse of continous nonvanishing function is continuous, as a ratio of continuous functions, one of them constantly equal $1.$ The inverse of nonvanishing holomorphic function in $\mathbb{D}$ is holomorphic as a ratio of holomorphic functions, again one of them equal $1.$